# TCustomDataSet C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I'm looking for an example of a TCustomDataSet implementation in C++ beyond the TTextDataset example that ships as an example project within C++ Builder.

The TTextDataset is hard to learn from because the code is not documented very well and it only shows a single field example.

I've created my own class that descends TDataSet and it mostly works however, the GUI controls (grids mostly) don't work 100% for certain use cases.

Anyone have some good links on this topic...

Here is a link to the example code I used to study from:
http://195.19.138.139:3000/p/SOFTWARE/temp/CBuilder5/Examples/DBTasks/TextData/textdataset.cpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a couple of examples. but unfortunately they are in Delphi, but you should get the idea:
[Example 1](http://dn.codegear.com/article/20587)
[Example 2](http://www.carterconsulting.org.uk/Articles/cdspt3.PDF)

The second one goes into a bit more explanation and is one I used to base a custom dataset on that did binding to UI (In delphi).

Comment: I already knew of those examples - Thanks!  I really have a hard time understanding the object pascal.  I can follow most of it and I have used those examples to make corrections in my own class but I'm still having problems that would most likely be more apparent to me if I had a C++ implementation